# Cannot call variables inside try-catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm trying to make an error proof program using try catch but it doesn't work as I expected

```
double num;

Console.Write("Input a number: ");
try
{
   num = Console.ReadLine(); // Don't mind this, I know this is a mistake
}
catch
{
   Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a number!");
}
Console.Write(num); // Error use of unassigned local variables 'num'. why??
```

What I thought of is the program will try to assign the value to the `num`. If it fails then the program will display a custom error <s>then stop the process</s>. Otherwise, it skipped `catch` then display a value which user entered before. Instead, the program doesn't work because num is not assigned. What is the proper way of using try-catch then?

Comment: Change your first line to `double num = 0;`. If you want the program to stop, you can exit out of your program with a return statement or throw a more specific error with a `throw` statement

Comment: Answers here notwithstanding im keen to know more about your mention in the question *display a custom error then stop the process.* - what do you mean by "stop the process" ? What are you expecting the program to stop doing? What will it start doing instead? When it finishes executing the code inside the "catch" block, where do you think the program will go next? I ask this because the way you've phrased the question implies an underlying misunderstanding of how c# programs flow so I'd like to get to addressing it

Comment: @CaiusJard this is the danger of me being self-taught programmer. I just conclude what I saw. I thought the ```catch``` is an alternative of ```return;``` so I expect the program stopped going to the next step if it catches an error. I might misunderstand somehow.

Comment: There should be more compiler errors, you have to include them all. Currently your question is a riddle which is harder to answer without having all details at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, not a double. Also, every variable must be initialized before it is used. You can modify your program like this:

```
double num = double.MinValue;

Console.Write("Input a number: ");
try
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    num = double.Parse(input);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a number!");
}

// Your output will still be double.MinValue if your catch block is hit. Probably not the best program flow.
Console.Write(num);
```

Here's an alternative (and better) approach:

```
if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var parsed))
    Console.WriteLine(parsed);
else
    Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a number!");
```

This solution is better because it avoids throwing an exception as part of ordinary program flow control.

Comment: Good catch! Edited it.

Comment: `If it fails then the program will display a custom error then stop the process.` I think you'd be better to move that `Write` inside the `try`.

Comment: @mjwills what the OP means by that is very much open question for me. I'd like to know if they think that all code after a try catch block is subject to some kind of implicit return inside the catch.. seems clear some misunderstanding of program flow is going on

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to parse the `Console.ReadLine()` into a double, you could use`TryParse()`method:

```
Console.Write("Input: ");
string userInput = Console.WriteLine();
double num;

if (double.TryParse(userInput, out num) == false) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(userInput +" is not a number");
    return;
}

Console.Write(num);
```

Secondly, I would recommend you to set a `return` into the catch in order to not to do anything with the num value in case you enter into it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that there is an error in your try block, there isn't anything in the catch block to set the value of num. If you were to display the value of num at that point, there wouldn't be anything to show. Try and give num a default value that would indicate to you that there was some sort of error, or put everything into the try block:

```
Console.Write("Input a number: ");
try
{
   double num;
   num = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.Write(num);
}
catch
{
   Console.WriteLine("The value you entered is not a number!");
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, not a double. Also, by declaring `num` in the try block, the poster's last line of code has no access to it.